# Can I use hosts.allow hosts.deny files to restrict access to my websites (Nginx)?

Tags: linux, nginx, debian, cloudflare

Is there any way how to use hosts.allow and hosts.deny files to restrict access to the websites (Nginx)?

This does not work:

```
hosts.allow file content:
nginx: SOME-IP-ADDRESS

hosts.deny file content:
nginx: ALL
```

I am going to use Cloudflare services and want allow connections to Nginx only from Cloudflare IP addresses but can't find a way how to do it.

Yes, I know, I can allow/deny connections by IP address in Nginx configuration file but not in this case because I use:

```
set_real_ip_from CLOUDFLARE_IP_ADDRESSES;
real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
```

which converts Cloudflare IP addresses into users IP addresses and after that I can not know if the request is coming from Cloudflare. I want to allow connections only from Cloudflare but at the same time I want to know the real IP address of each http request.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just drop the non cloudflare connections at the firewall then

Comment: `Is there any way` this is the same as "does hosts.allow work?" - of course it works.

Answer (score 0):

Only allow [CloudFlare IP addresses](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/) through your firewall.